# Regex para pegar sequencia de numeros iguais

Tags: javascript, regex, validação

Estou precisando fazer uma validação usando regex, como eu faço para validar se uma string ta vindo com numeros repitidos? por exemplo "1111","2222","3333"

Comment: Com no minimo quantos digitos?

Comment: sim, com 4 numeros no minimo e 15 no máximo

Comment: Conseguiste resolver este problema? as respostas foram úteis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testa assim: `/^(\d)\1+$/`.

[Essa regex](https://regex101.com/r/dY9dW2/1) cria um grupo de captura para um caracter *typo numero* e depois compara esse primeiro numero uma ou mais vezes. O `\1` vai buscar o que foi capturado no primeiro grupo de captura e o `+` exige que seja o mesmo 1 ou mais vezes.

```
var testes = [
    '111',
    '123',
    '222',
    '334'
];
var regex = /^(\d)\1+$/;
var resultado = testes.map(function (str) {
    return regex.test(str);
});
alert(resultado); // true, false, true, false
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vospcr9q/

Para usar entre 4 e 15 numeros iguais [podes fazer assim](https://regex101.com/r/fO3lM2/1): `/^(\d)\1{3,14}$/`

Comment: +1 muito legal. O que o `\1` faz exatamente? Nunca tinha visto!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters juntei explicação e link para a regex.

Comment: É o resultado do primeiro grupo, se tivesse outro grupo seria \2, outras linguaguens usam $1 por exemplo. @WallaceMaxters.

Comment: Acabei fazendoa  pergunta @rray http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93996/para-que-serve-o-1-na-express%C3%A3o-regular-em-javascript

Comment: Ok. Ou vocês respondem minha pergunta, ou vou ter que deletar :p

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer verificar se os números estão em sequência, com 4 ou mais repetídos, você pode fazer assim:

```
/^(\d\d)\d{0,4}\1$/.test(1222); // FALSE
/^(\d\d)\d{0,4}\1$/.test(122222); // TRUE
```

Se quiser aumentar a validação da sequência, basta alterar o valor `4` do trecho `{0,4}`