# Para que serve o \1 na expressão regular, em javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Estava dando uma olhada nessa resposta do @Sergio aqui no stackoverlow:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/93995/4995

Lá tinha um trecho de código assim:

```
/^(\d)\1+$/.test(111)
```

O que faz exatamente o `\1` nessa expressão regular?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Se tiveres um ou mais grupos de captura na regex esse `\1` vai buscar o valor capturado no primeiro grupo. Como que uma variável que assume o valor do grupo. Se houver mais que um podes usar `\2`, etc.

Por exemplo:

- `/^(\w)\1(\d)\2$/`

aceita strings com duas letras iguais seguida de dois numeros iguais duas a duas.
Por exemplo `aa11` ou `bb33` ([exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/cO2sJ5/1)).

- `/^(\w)(\d)\1\2$/`

é parecido com o exemplo em cima mas aceita padrões intercalados.
Por exemplo `a1a1` ou `b3b3` ([exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/dN0dP5/1)).

Comment: são chamados de `retrovisores`, pois se utilizam de algo que já foi capturado.

Comment: Apenas para terminar de sanar a dúvida: Isso só existe em javascript?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters isso existe em quase todas as linguagens de programação. Pelos vistos RE2 não suporta, mas a maioria suporta. Dá uma olhada [aqui, na coluna "Backreference"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines#cite_note-backref-19).

Answer (score 4):

É o resultado do primeiro grupo que é representando pelos `( )`, então barra número (`\1`)  obter o valor dele. Outras linguagens usa cifrão, ex: `$1`.

Expressões regulares tem utilidades no dia dia, digamos que você tenha um arquivo de texto cheio de inserts onde as datas estão no formato `dd/mm/yyyy` com um editor adequado é possível converter para `yyyy-mm-dd` com replace.

23/10/2015

Utilize `([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})` para caputrar a data e `\3\2\1` isso vai trocar a posição do ano pela do dia, depois é so trocar o separador de `\` para `-` e data ficará 2015-10-23.

Comment: O interessante é que geralmente o `$1` é utilizado "do outro lado" da `regexp`. Quer dizer, pós captura. Igual `preg_replace('/(\w+)/, 'Peguei isso $1', 'Aqui')`