# Identificar caracteres numéricos repetidos em sequência

Tags: regex

Com a [expressão](https://regex101.com/r/xffb4S/1) `[\d]{9}` eu consigo identificar caracteres numéricos caso se repitam nove vezes em sequência, porém eu desejo apenas identificar caso sejam os mesmos caracteres, por exemplo:

```
111111111 // false
222222222 // false
333333333 // false
077546997 // true
123566566 // true
```

Como deve ser tratado esse agrupamento?

Comment: `(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9){9}`

Comment: @BrunoRB seria a negação disso, deveria dar `false` quando essa regex der `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar assim: `(?!(\d)\1{8})\d{9}`

Basicamente duas partes:

- o que não deve ser capturado: `(?!(\d)\1{8})`
- o formato esperado da string `\d{9}`

A parte de *negative look ahead* que está dentro da tag `(?! .... )` procura strings que não devem ser aceites. Ora fazendo um grupo de captura e depois usar essa captura como referência com [`\1` como expliquei nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93996/129). Basicamente ele pega o primeiro numero e diz que deve ter 8 x o mesmo numero (dentro dessa campo de negação).

#### Exemplo: https://regex101.com/r/6fv4BV/1

Comment: Boa resposta Sérgio (+1)

Comment: Agora deu pra entender bem o uso do "retrovisor" `\1` na expressão.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a expressão [`(\d)\1{8}`](https://regex101.com/r/fCQYg2/1).

Onde:

- `(\d)`: Grupo de captura, somente dígitos `0-9`.
- `\1{8}`: Faz referência ao primeiro grupo de captura. Vai corresponder ao mesmo padrão correspondido pelo grupo de captura, oito vezes. Veja mais detalhes [**aqui**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

```js
console.log(/(\d)\1{8}/.test('111111111'));
console.log(/(\d)\1{8}/.test('222222222'));
console.log(/(\d)\1{8}/.test('333333333'));
console.log(/(\d)\1{8}/.test('444444444'));
console.log(/(\d)\1{8}/.test('077546997'));
```

### Edição

A expressão usada na resposta vai corresponder à números repetidos em sequência, para fazer o oposto, veja as respostas do [**@Sergio**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/156832/6454) e [**@Allan**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/156820/6454)!

Comment: Acho que o Marcelo quer o oposto, ou seja `111111111 // false`.

Comment: Boa resposta stderr (+1)

Comment: A resposta foi ótima, porém é realmente o inverso assim como o @Sergio respondeu.

Comment: @Sergio Realmente...editei a resposta e coloquei isso, acho que vou manter a resposta assim mesmo, talvez outras pessoas tenham dúvidas semelhantes.

Comment: @stderr boa. A resposta do Allan é basicamente igual à tua, ele juntou depois `e negar a sua saída`, que é o mesmo que poderia ser feito com a tua também.

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção é utilizar a expressão regular abaixo e negar a sua saída:

```
0{9}|1{9}|2{9}|3{9}|4{9}|5{9}|6{9}|7{9}|8{9}|9{9}
```

Resultado:

> 111111111 // casa
>
> 222222222 // casa
>
> 333333333 // casa
>
> 077546997 // não casa
>
> 123566566 // não casa